# run a function concurrently with client.run() in discord

Tags: python, async-await, concurrency, discord.py

so i have a discord bot and also another function that i want to run, but i want them to run concurrently but i couldn't make them run without one of them blocking the other, here's an example code
ps: disnake is a fork of dicord.py so it works the same mostly

```
import disnake
import time

bot = commands.Bot()

async on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello bot":
        await message.channel.send("hey user")

x=0
def counting():
   while True:
      x += 1 
      print(x)
      time.sleep(1)

#here is the issue mostly
bot.run(token)
counting()
```

i want the bot to run normally, while the other function is running and counting "1" "2" on my terminal, but i can't get to make them both work

Comment: Why not use threading?

Comment: @AD_DAB, did the solution I proposed worked for you?

Comment: @davide it doesn't work, i tried to make it work but didn't work with this script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disnake is an `async-await` library, which means that you should use non-blocking functions. Moreover, the fonctions you want to make concurrent should be `async` and contain `await` suspension points in order to let other concurrent routines an opportunity to execute.

The issue is that `Bot.run()` is a blocking call as the documentation mentions. Moreover your `counting()` function is not `async` and does not contain any `await`. Thus, the two functions cannot run concurrently. Also, you should not use `time.sleep()` with AsyncIO as it is a blocking operation. You should use `asyncio.sleep()`.

the program could look like this:

```py
import asyncio
import disnake

async on_message(message):
  if message.content == "hello bot":
    await message.channel.send("hey user")

async def run_bot(bot: Bot, token: str):
  try:
    await bot.start(token)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    await bot.close()
    
async def count():
  count = 0
  while True:
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    count += 1
    print(count)

async def main():
  bot = commands.Bot()
  token = "<user_token>"
   
  await asyncio.gather(
    count(),
    run_bot(bot, token)
  )
 
  await bot.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())
```

Note: you did not seem to use `on_message()` in your code, which is probably an error.